# R - add column that counts sequentially within groups but repeats for duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm looking for a solution to add the column "desired_result" preferably using dplyr and/or ave(). See the data frame here, where the group is "section" and the unique instances I want my "desired_results" column to count sequentially are in "exhibit":

```
structure(list(section = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), exhibit = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
desired_result = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("section", 
"exhibit", "desired_result"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: `df$desired <- c("a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3)[df$exhibit]`

Comment: I don't think your "rules" are clear enough. Are your data sorted, as they are in your example dataset here?

Comment: @Khashaa sorry, for the purposes of an example data frame, I shortened full names to single letters.  There are a lot of names so I'll need to handle many more instances than just 3.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto, these names are not in alphabetical order, and are randomly occurring, so you're right, my data frame is misleading.  The important part is that when the count reaches a duplicate in the exhibit column, it should repeat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dense_rank` it is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(section) %>% 
  mutate(desire=dense_rank(exhibit))
#  section exhibit desired_result desire
#1       1       a              1      1
#2       1       b              2      2
#3       1       c              3      3
#4       1       c              3      3
#5       2       a              1      1
#6       2       b              2      2
#7       2       b              2      2
#8       2       c              3      3
```

Answer (score 5):

I've recently pushed a function `rleid()` to `data.table` (currently available on the development version, 1.9.5), which does exactly this. If you're interested, you can install it by following [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
require(data.table) # 1.9.5, for `rleid()`
require(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(section) %>% 
  mutate(desired_results=rleid(exhibit))

#   section exhibit desired_result desired_results
# 1       1       a              1               1
# 2       1       b              2               2
# 3       1       c              3               3
# 4       1       c              3               3
# 5       2       a              1               1
# 6       2       b              2               2
# 7       2       b              2               2
# 8       2       c              3               3
```

Comment: Does this produce the same result as Khashaa's answer using `dense_rank`? I don't have data.table 1.9.5 installed yet.

Comment: For ordered data it returns the same as `dense_rank`. In general, seems `rleid(x)` is like `rep(1:length(rle(x)$values), rle(x)$lengths)`.

Comment: `rleid()` works with more than 1 column as well. Ex: `with(DF, rleid(section, exhibit))`

Answer (score 2):

If exact enumeration is necessary and you need the desired result to be consistent (so that a same exhibit in a different section will always have the same number), you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(section = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                 exhibit = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'))
if (is.null(saveLevels <- levels(df$exhibit)))
    saveLevels <- sort(unique(df$exhibit)) ## or levels(factor(df$exhibit))
df %>%
    group_by(section) %>%
    mutate(answer = as.integer(factor(exhibit, levels = saveLevels)))
## Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
## Groups: section
##   section exhibit answer
## 1       1       a      1
## 2       1       b      2
## 3       1       c      3
## 4       1       c      3
## 5       2       a      1
## 6       2       b      2
## 7       2       b      2
## 8       2       c      3
```

If/when a new `exhibit` appears in subsequent `section`s, they should get newly enumerated results. (Notice the last `exhibit` is different.)

```
df2 <- data.frame(section = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                  exhibit = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'd'))
if (is.null(saveLevels2 <- levels(df2$exhibit)))
    saveLevels2 <- sort(unique(df2$exhibit))
df2 %>%
    group_by(section) %>%
    mutate(answer = as.integer(factor(exhibit, levels = saveLevels2)))
## Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
## Groups: section
##   section exhibit answer
## 1       1       a      1
## 2       1       b      2
## 3       1       c      3
## 4       1       c      3
## 5       2       a      1
## 6       2       b      2
## 7       2       b      2
## 8       2       d      4
```